# How to display accordion items in line?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I made an accordion and i want to display in it some pictures, but i want them to be in line, like a row, right now they are displayed vertically i want them to be shown horizontally, ive tried a lot of stuff and ive googled but couldn't get my answer.

heres my HTML code.

```
<div id="accordion">
   <h3 class="FirstItem">Christmass trees </h3>
   <div class="SecondItem">

   <img  src="Pics/Products/Trees/Xtree1.jpg" />
   <img  src="Pics/Products/Trees/Xtree2.jpg" />
   <img  src="Pics/Products/Trees/Xtree3.jpg" />
   <img  src="Pics/Products/Trees/Xtree4.jpg" />
   <img  src="Pics/Products/Trees/Xtree5.jpg" />
   <img  src="Pics/Products/Trees/Xtree6.jpg" />
   <img  src="Pics/Products/Trees/Xtree7.jpg" />
   <img  src="Pics/Products/Trees/Xtree8.jpg" />
   <img  src="Pics/Products/Trees/Xtree9.jpg" />
   <img  src="Pics/Products/Trees/Xtree10.jpg" />

   </div>
</div>
```

CSS code:-

```
 #accordion{
    width: 700px;

}
#accordion .FirstItem{
    background: url("../Pics/WhiteBack.jpg")repeat 0 0;
    color: #808080 ;
}
#accordion .SecondItem{
    background: url("../Pics/WhiteStars.jpg")repeat 0 0;
    height: 200px;
}
```

JS code if u need it.

```
$(function(){
   $("#accordion").accordion({collapsible: true, active: false});
});
```

Comment: What's the problem ? https://jsfiddle.net/zlen/9jb7f15v/

Comment: They look inline to me

Comment: for they don't look in line, but i want them to be all pictures in line and nothing to go down u know what i mean ? i want them all on one row. and to be able to go let's say from pic 1 to pic 10 using the navigation bar.

Comment: So you want them to stay inline regardless of browser size? Are you using any responsive framework? Bootsrap, Foundation, Susy, Skeleton, Anything?

Comment: no not really .... i am trying to make a website for training purposes, so far i know html/css/java script/jQuery..   i am a begginer =P.

Comment: Integrating bootstrap is time consuming but very rewarding.  You should try that.  In most professional environments you work for you'll be asked to know at least one responsive framework and bootstrap is one of the most common

Comment: @Amanda go to http://getbootstrap.com/ download it, include it in the root of your site, change your classes and use the accordion component they offer, and so on. You'll end up with a better and more maintanable site. The days of doing everything from scratch are over. Think of jQuery for instance. Before jQuery we had to do all JS from scratch. jQuery took care of all the main work and it is very common for devs to use it as a foundation. Same with HTML/CSS frameworks

Comment: Try `#accordion{white-space:nowrap;}` if **[this](https://jsfiddle.net/68pf7mgg/)** is what you want.

Comment: YES Pangloss thats exactly what i wanted .... thx i will try, and LOTUSMS i will try and learn, i am at the begging of my web development long journey , but i will try and learn as much as possible, now i will try and expand my knowledge of bootstrap since i have no idea what they are. thx all for your comments and help.

Comment: @Pangloss it worked thx a lot. your a life saver.

Comment: Glad to hear that helped. You're welcome!

Answer (score 2):

Im sorry if i caused a bit of confusion, all i had to do was to add

`white-space: nowrap;`   to my CSS code so it looks like this.

```
#accordion{
    width: 700px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

I am just adding this answer for future people who might want to do something similar.

This question was answered @Pangloss

Answer (score -1):

using ul, li.

```css
li{
  display:inline-block;
  }
```

```html
<ul>
    <li><img src=""/></li>
    <li><img src=""/></li>
  <li><img src=""/></li>
  <li><img src=""/></li>
  <li><img src=""/></li>
  <li><img src=""/></li>
  <li><img src=""/></li>
  </ul>
```